# Set content-type HTTP header for 404 page in TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-404, typo3-9.x

I am making a webservice using TYPO3. Everything in the frontend should be JSON with HTTP header `Content-Type: application/json`, however I am unable to change the `Content-Type` header for the 404 page. Whatever I try, it's always `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. How can I change this?

This is my basic `page` TypoScript configuration:

```
page = PAGE
page {
  config {
    disableAllHeaderCode = 1
    disablePrefixComment = 1
    xhtml_cleaning = 0
    admPanel = 0
  }
  10 = USER
  10 {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = MyExt
    pluginName = MyPlugin
    vendorName = MyVendor
  }
}
```

The extension uses `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\View\JsonView`.

I've already tried adding the header using `config.additionalHeaders.10.header = Content-Type: application/json`. I've also tried setting `[FE][pageNotFound_handling]` to `USER_FUNCTION:...` and setting the headers in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself. From TYPO3 9.5 the default page not found handling can be overridden in the site configuration:

```
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: 404
    errorHandler: PHP
    errorPhpClassFQCN: Vendor\MyExt\PageErrorHandler\PageNotFoundHandler
```

And in EXT:MyExt/Classes/PageErrorHandler/PageNotFoundHandler.php:

```php
<?php
namespace Vendor\MyExt\PageErrorHandler;

/*
 * This file is part of the TYPO3 CMS project.
 *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License, either version 2
 * of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!
 */

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\PageErrorHandler\PageErrorHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Class PageNotFoundHandler
 */
class PageNotFoundHandler implements PageErrorHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * Handle page error
     *
     * @param ServerRequestInterface $request
     * @param string $message
     * @param array $reasons
     * @return ResponseInterface
     */
    public function handlePageError(ServerRequestInterface $request, string $message, array $reasons = []): ResponseInterface
    {
        $response = new Response(404, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'], '{"error":"Not found"}');
        return $response;
    }
}
```